# DataDog Log - Search a sequence with wildcards

Tags: search, datadog

In DataDog's log search, I want to match the following sentence. But I have not been able to do so.

```
•   Request failed with status code 500  
•   Request failed with status code 525  
•   Request failed with status code 512
```

**The status code can be any value from 500 to 599.**

[image]

I have tried using the following searches. Now of them work.

```
•   "Request failed with status code 5*"
•   "Request failed with status code 5**"
•   "*Request failed with status code 5*"

•   "Request failed with status code 5?*"
•   "Request failed with status code 5??*"
•   "Request failed with status code 5??"

•   "*Request?failed?with?status?code?5*"  
•   "Request?failed?with?status?code?5??"  
•   "*Request?failed?with?status?code?5??*"
```

These work. But the result is wrong.

```
"Request failed with status code" 5??  
"Request failed with status code" 5*
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you search for the status code as a [facet](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/explorer/search_syntax/#numerical-values)?

Comment: @EricAllen, no, it is not defined as a tag. The string is in the content message.

Answer (score 3):

update:

looks like `?` doesn't match on spaces

query `HTTP responded 5??`
[image]

they need to be escaped: query `HTTP\ responded?5??`

[image]

So I would try `Request\ failed\ with\ status\ code\ 5??` as the query.

However I would recommend parsing the log with a pipeline so you can just make an easier query like `@request.status:failed @status.code:[500 TO 599]. To avoid having to dealing with all the escaping and wilcarding

---

Wildcards don't work inside quotes, [they will be treated as literal](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/explorer/search_syntax/#escaping-of-special-characters).

just search for `Request?failed?with?status?code?5??`

You also don't need to surround the query with `*`, they are there by default when searching a message.

Comment: Thank you I tried this, but it doesn't give me any results. It says "`No matching results found`". Not sure why.
I also tried "`SampleString?Request?failed?with?status?code?5??`". But it also comes with no results found.
I used only this string as well. Then comes '`Oops, an error has occurred. Please try again or reload the page`' error even after trying multiple times.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this matches. But it also matches other logs. Please see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyUNy.png). Also, in this case, I'm not sure why '?' doesn't match spaces.

Comment: Yes, that would make perfect sense. But I can't change it.

Comment: ah i'm silly, spaces can be matched by just escaping them. updated my answer again

Comment: Thanks. Again, [this is the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyUNy.png).